# Selenium Webdriver with firefox driver not starting from batch command file on windows with error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have written some script in Selenium web-driver which runs absolutely fine when i run it from Intellij and use Firefox driver.

However i have written a batch file which call the compiled jar file of selenium script through command line and i am facing a problem here, which is as followed:
when i run the batch file, i observed an instance of Firefox starts and then closes and then again one more Firefox instance is started. which result script waiting for Firefox driver for set time-out and then gives exception

"org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127
.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:"

so as i feel the first Firefox instance closing and new Firefox instance starting is the real problem, but I don't know what is causing this behaviour while running it from command line with command "java -jar SeleniumTest.jar 2 1".

Also, one NOTE to add. batch file i.e. from command line(command "java -jar SeleniumTest.jar 2 2")  it is working absolutely fine for Chrome Driver

One more note, the command line is working upto Firefox v40, for Firefox 43+ version it is giving this. however i have latest set of jars from selenium i.e. v2.53. I feel these latest releases are not compatible with Firefox 43+.

Comment: looks interesting..generally i will use ANT which helps in batch execution. did you tried this if it fits your needs?

Comment: the last stable combination that i could find for selenium was selenium 2.48.2 with FF 41.0.2..pls give that a try

Comment: that error is usually due to incompatibility between driver and firefox

Comment: I worked at a big company, that had some weird self-developed FF extensions, preinstalled on everyone's machine. At the first start, FF installed the extension, and restarted itself. It caused me some pain till I found out that the extension is fooling me. But enough about me: do you have any extensions installed on the FF instance started by Selenium? (I had the same issue with some localization plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Does `SeleniumTest.jar` contain the Selenium dependencies as well. If not I am assuming that you have setup the `CLASSPATH` to the Selenium Jars. You might be having the latest Selenium Jar in Intellij but your `CLASSPATH` might contain an older version which is causing the incompatibility.

Open command prompt and type `echo %CLASSPATH%` to check the `CLASSPATH' and validate it.